# GSheets automated script attributes automated changes to "anonymous", can this be changed anywhere?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script in Google Sheets right now that runs every hour, but when it runs it changes the page to say "Last edit made 1 hour ago (or whatever time) by anonymous". Is there a way I can attribute that edit to either the user that ran the macro or just have it say like "Auto-run Script"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from this [thread](https://tags.hawksey.info/forums/topic/anonymous-editing-in-gdocs/), cells with formula which update with new values are recorded as anonymous. This part of the script is actually in a library and it appears the library is recorded as an anonymous user.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but it's in a company Suite so the only people with access to it will be named, so at least if it says anonymous I know it's just the script and not someone actually changing things. Thanks!